# Correct Path to Local Volume Files When Using Delta Live Tables

Tags: sql, databricks, delta-live-tables

I put the following file in a local Databricks volume named livelandingtest:
/Volumes/seary_test/default/livelandingtest/TIOBE/TIOBE-2018-09.csv
[image]

Also, I have this code that tries to do an autoload on any files inside the livelandingtest/TIOBE directory:

```
-- https://www.databricks.com/discover/pages/getting-started-with-delta-live-tables
CREATE LIVE TABLE TIOBE_Live_Test_Bronze
COMMENT "Auto Loader Test"
TBLPROPERTIES ("quality" = "bronze")
AS
SELECT * FROM cloud_files(
   "dbfs:/Volumes/seary_test/default/livelandingtest/TIOBE/*", 
   "csv", 
   map("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
);
```

When I run the above code as a Delta Live Tables Workflow, I get this error:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot access the UC Volume path from this location. Path was /Volumes/seary_test/default/livelandingtest/TIOBE/**

What syntax should I use in my FROM clause on lines 6-10 to access the CSV files in my local volume /Volumes/seary_test/default/livelandingtest?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't necessarily the path as listed above. It seems I wasn't choosing the correct settings when creating my Delta Live Tables (DLT) pipeline. When I chose my seary_test catalog under Destination Storage Options and added a STREAMING keyword on Line#2 of the above code, my DLT pipeline was able to startup:
[image]

**STREAMING keyword was added on Line#2 below**

```
-- https://www.databricks.com/discover/pages/getting-started-with-delta-live-tables
CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE TIOBE_Live_Test_Bronze
COMMENT "Auto Loader Test"
TBLPROPERTIES ("quality" = "bronze")
AS
SELECT * FROM cloud_files(
   "dbfs:/Volumes/seary_test/default/livelandingtest/TIOBE/*", 
   "csv", 
   map("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
);
```

Since I'm new to DLT, I'm not completely sure why I needed the STREAMING keyword. I guess that has something to do with my use of the cloud_files function. However, the **key factor** for accessing the /Volumes/**seary_test**/default/livelandingtest/TIOBE/* path seems to be the need to select my **seary_test** catalog under the Destination section when creating the pipeline via the Web GUI.